# Cant find bug in python client socket program

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, connection, client

I want to clarify. This works. The program connects to the server and the server just sends a welcome message, But it gives me that error when the server sends the message back to the client. and I cant figure it out and Im new to sockets so Im trying to also learn from this mistake.. the **entire** error message is at the bottom in comments

```
import socket

class client:
    def __init__(self,s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)):
        self.s = s

    def connect(self,server_ip = 'ip'): # i replaced the actual ip with 'ip' 
    for safety reasons (obviously)
        self.s.connect(('ip', 12345))
        while True:
           data = self.s.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
           if not data:
               break
           print(data)
        self.s.close()

 if __name__ == '__main__':
 cl = client()
 cl.connect()
```

This is the Error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "client.py", line 18, in <module>
   cl.connect()
 File "client.py", line 10, in connect
   data = self.s.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
 OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file desscriptor
```

Comment: Check your program and make sure that it does not call `self.s.close()` inside the `while` loop that reads data from the socket.  (The indentation of the posted program is syntactically incorrect, so clearly it's not exactly what you're running when you encounter the error.)

Comment: @ottomeister oh apologies on the indentations not being accurate I was dead when I was posting this, ill edit it

Comment: @ottomeister calling close() outside the while loop worked, thank you :)